# Replace a single node with multiple nodes using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I have some input tags that are placeholders that I am replacing with some HTML. A lot of the time the HTML I'm replacing them with is only one tag, which is easy enough:

```
HtmlNode node = HtmlNode.CreateNode(sReplacementString);
inputNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(node, inputNode);
```

However if I want to replace `inputNode` with two or more nodes `HtmlNode.CreateNode(sReplacementString)` only reads the first node. Is there a way to do a replace where `sReplacementString` is multiple tags?

Comment: Can you provide more context?  You might be able to replace the node with a div containing your 2 children or something like that.

Comment: @SteveDanner I don't want any extra markup. `inputNode.ParentNode` could be anything, hence the need for the replace function to work!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no *direct* way to do it. `HtmlNode.CreateNode` method creates a single node from the HTML snippet, if there are several nodes there, the first one is created only.

As a workaround you could create a temporary node, create its child nodes from the `sReplacementString`, and then append these child nodes right after the `inputNode` node, and, finally, remove the `inputNode`.

```
var temp = doc.CreateElement("temp");
temp.InnerHtml = sReplacementString;
var current = inputNode;
foreach (var child in temp.ChildNodes)
{
    inputNode.ParentNode.InsertAfter(child, current);
    current = child;
}
inputNode.Remove();
```

Comment: Spot on, though I didn't have a Remove function so I used `inputNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(inputNode);`

Comment: Was exactly what I needed, I spent a long time thinking this would be an existing method, but seems with HtmlAgilityPack there are random things you need to write for yourself quite often.